# Can you build a structopt parser that takes the rest of the command line (or multiple arguments)?

Tags: rust, command-line-arguments, structopt

`structopt` has a neat feature where it can it accept a typed argument for `Vec<T>` that will gobble the rest of the command line.

```rust
#[structopt(long, short)]
values: Vec<u32>,
```

It also has the [ability to accept a type you create](https://docs.rs/structopt/0.3.23/structopt/#custom-string-parsers),

> If the field type does not have a `FromStr` implementation, or you would like to provide a custom parsing scheme other than `FromStr`, you may provide a custom string parser using `parse(...)`

Can the type that you create not be a scalar and either have multiple values or wrap a `Vec<T>` is there a method to create a [custom parser](https://docs.rs/structopt/0.3.23/structopt/#custom-string-parsers) for a type that wraps `Vec<T>` but reorders it's arguments or a struct that includes more than one field, for example like this

```
struct Positionals {
  first: String,
  increment: String,
  last: String
}
```

I need a different structure because the arguments name is contingent on the ordering, (if there is one argument it's just "last" if there is two arguments the first argument is not last, it's "first" and the second argument is "last"). I was wondering if there was a way to write a parser that understands these nuances (as above) or can reorder a vector to accommodate for them.

Comment: Wrapper of `Vec<T>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No

I don't believe this is currently possible. I opened up an [RFC for a parser that gets a `vec::Drain`, or a parser that get the rest of the command line](https://github.com/TeXitoi/structopt/issues/499). I also asked for alternative ways to accomplish this. The response was,

> The `clap` infrastructure (which `structopt` only expose on top of struct attribute) doesn't support this as far as I know. Validators in clap (that is named parser in `structopt`, as they validate and parse) are implemented on each argument, not on a set of arguments.

Comment: Errr... there is a way to kinda get it done :P let me see if i can put something as an answer in a bit

Comment: @AhmedMasud I'm marking this answer as accepted, will re-evaluate if you want to answer though.